# What underlying semantic notions connect 'campus' to the PIE root *kam-p- (to bend)?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

Univ. Texas's page on [kam-p-    'to bend'](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P0834.html) states: 'Semantic Field: to Bend'. Then I saw *campus* (plain, campus, open field) listed, but what semantic notions underlie it and 'to bend'?
I can understand that any corner contains a bend, but how did 2 shift semantically to 3?

> [ [Etymonline:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=campus) ] [...] [3.] from Latin *campus* "a field," probably properly "an expanse surrounded" (by woods, higher ground, etc.),
>   [2.] from PIE **kampos* "a corner, cove,"
>   [1.] from root **kamp-* "to bend" [...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This r/asklinguistics](https://old.reddit.com/r/asklinguistics/comments/hlteqg/what_semantic_notions_underlie_campus_with_the/) post answers my question.

> [gnorrn](https://old.reddit.com/user/gnorrn). 4 points 6 days ago
>
> De Vaan, *Etymological Dictionary of Latin*, gives a derivation from Proto-Italic **kampo-*, "field", and also supplies Balto-Slavic cognates meaning "corner".
>
> This suggests that the semantic development into Proto-Italic may have been something like "bend" -> "corner" -> "area bounded by corners".

[ecphrastic](https://old.reddit.com/user/ecphrastic). 6 days ago

> The source you've quoted lists *campus* 'field' as probably properly a 'surrounded expanse'. "Surrounded" seems to be the critical semantic similarity here. A corner is an area surrounded on multiple sides. A field is a type of landscape, which someone might define in opposition to the other landscapes it borders, such that you could imagine *campus* originally meaning a minimally vegetated area surrounded or bordered by thickly vegetated areas, and eventually shifting slightly to mean the terrain of the minimally vegetated area itself.
>
> The English word *clearing* lies somewhere in that same spectrum of meaning. A *clearing* strictly speaking is a small treeless area in a forest, especially from logging. It's not too far-fetched to think it could come to mean something like 'meadow', but right now it's a word that defines treeless terrain in opposition to adjacent forest.